# Get strength, velocity, direction of force field at specific position

Tags: python, particles

is it possible to get parameters like strength and direaction of a forcefield at a specific position with Python?

For example I would like to know how strong a turbulence field is and in which direction it goes at position 1.0/1.0/1.0.